# Find characters from same homeworld as Chewbacca

Tags: python, pandas

The problem is

> Find the names of all characters which are from the same homeworld as Chewbacca

My code is

```
Chewbacca = df.loc[df.name == "Chewbacca"],"homeworld"
print(Chewbacca)

df.loc[df.homeworld == "Kashyyyk"]
```

I first found Chewbacca's homeworld and then filtered it. Is there more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The first improvement you can do is to reuse the variable you created in the first lookup to provide the value for the second lookup instead of hardcoding it.

```
chewbaccas_home = df.loc[df.name == "Chewbacca"]["homeworld"].iloc[0]
print(chewbaccas_home)

df.loc[df.homeworld == chewbaccas_home]
```

Notice the brackets around `"homeworld"`. What `["homeworld"]` does is selecting the column "homeworld" the dataframe returned by `df.loc[df.name == "Chewbacca"]`. The `.iloc[0]` part returns the first value from that column (there could be multiple values because the values in the `name` column do not have to be unique).

You can also get rid of the `.loc` accessor and use `.homeworld` instead of `["homeworld"]` to reduce the number of characters.

```
chewbaccas_home = df[df.name == "Chewbacca"].homeworld.iloc[0]
df[df.homeworld == chewbaccas_home]
```